# pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from input file: end of file

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

Not going into details how that happened, all started with a corrupt DB. It was OK on the file-system level, but trying to:

```
select count(*) from mytable
```

resulted in the following:

> ERROR:  could not read block 257798 in file "pg_tblspc/16386/PG_9.6_201608131/16385/16506.1": read only 0 of 8192 bytes

The table is very large (~200GB) and contains some `bytea` columns with binary data. It is never updated, only inserted into and selected from.
I run pg_dump on it, it was working for a long time, produced a ~200GB file, but failed in the end with a similar error:

```
pg_dump -Z9 -Fc -d mydatabase -t mytable -v -f /datadir/mytable.backup
```

> pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table "mytable" failed: PQgetResult() failed.
>
> pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  could not read block 257798 in file "pg_tblspc/16386/PG_9.6_201608131/16385/16506.1": read only 0 of 8192 bytes
>
> pg_dump: The command was: COPY public.mytable (id, account_id, fetched, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) TO stdout;

Then I tried to restore it, again it was working a long time, in the end it took ~200GB space on that tablespace, however `select count(*) from mytable` returns `0`.

```
 pg_restore -Fc -d mydatabase -v /datadir/mytable.backup
```

> pg_restore: processing data for table "public.mytable"

and after a long time

> pg_restore: could not read from input file: end of file

On server side this resulted in:

> ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
>
> CONTEXT:  COPY mytable, line 14497030
>
> STATEMENT:  COPY mytable (id, account_id, fetched, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) FROM stdin
>
> LOG:  could not send data to client: Connection reset by peer
>
> FATAL:  connection to client lost

It looks like the pg_restore requested to abort the whole operation.

I would like to recover as many rows as possible, I suspect that all the data should be still there since it's basically immutable, and that just the last record is corrupted.

Is there a way to force Postgres to keep the records which were restored up till the failed one?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try to do something along the line of:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE my_primary_key < value ;
```

... and find at which point it fails. [This may be tedious, but you can just cut in half repeatedly, until you find the value that first fails.]

You will most probably need to alter the different settings that affect index usage, because you actually want to force the database to *use* the index, even if it actually must scan 99% of the table. You want it *not* to scan the page that *booms*.

If you can get `SELECT` to give you most of the data, you can then do something such as:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_2 AS 
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_primary_key < value;
```

and later on:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME TO my_table_old ;
ALTER TABLE my_table_2 RENAME TO my_table ;
```

... and you'll have all the data that could be retrieved. I wouldn't drop the old table, in case someone finds later on a better method of retrieving the missing info.

Best of luck.